# Are questions about Ethereum's core development team on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I've been reading about Mike Hearn's departure from Bitcoin XT. The supposed in-fighting between Bitcoin's core developers reads a bit like a soap opera.

It would be a shame if something similar were to happen with Ethereum, and there's no reason to expect it should. However, parallels between the technologies are always going to be drawn, if not simply because we're trying to create something decentralised while still having a centralised team of core developers.

These are the people who make decisions on how Ethereum is run and how it will develop, and these decisions affect all of Ethereum's users to one degree or another. As such, should questions about them be considered on-topic?

To give an example:

> "Which for-profit companies does Mr Core Dev work for?"

(If there's already a blanket SE policy against questions about individuals that I didn't know about [nor could find], then apologies in advance.)

Comment: this is what reddit is for, not stackexchange :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, generally speaking, this should be off topic. Stack Exchange was created for collaborative knowledge sharing, and the focus of this site is the ***subject* of Ethereum.**

Stack Exchange works really well for **technical support**, as long as we're not trying to outsource a project's entire customer support channel to Stack Exchange. These "insider baseball" issues a better left to other forums and are  *generally* hosted by facilities run by the project team itself. Questions about internal issues with the company, future directions, and feature requests/bug reports are best left to other forums. These are not a good fit for a Stack Exchange Q&A.

Comment: Fully agree discussions of individuals motivations falls under the "unanswerable" speculation category.

Comment: I agree. However, an exception to this should be cases where the question is asking about which organization develops which product. Ethereum development is incredibly decentralized and multiple organizations control/code multiple clients. In those cases, I think those questions can be answered.